# Adding user information to centralized logging with ELK stack

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am using ELK stack (first project) to centralize logs of a server and visualize some real-time statistics with Kibana. The logs are stored in an ES index and I have another index with user information (IP, name, demographics). I am trying to:

1. Join user information with the server logs, matching the IPs. I want to include this information in the Kibana dashboard (e.g. to show in real-time the username of the connected users).
2. Create new indexes with filtered and processed information (e.g. users that have visited more than 3 times certain url).

Which is the best design to solve those problems (e.g. include username in the logstash stage through a filter, do scheduled jobs,...)? If the processing task (2) gets more complex, would it be better to use MongoDB instead?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the user data now?  Mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to cross reference some log data with user data (containing IPs among other data) and just used elasticsearch's [bulk import API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).  This meant extracting the data from a RDBMS, converting it to JSON and outputting a flat file that adhered to the format desired by the bulk import API (basically prefixing a row that describes the index and type).

That should work for an initial import, then your delta could be achieved using triggers in whatever stores your user data.  Might simply write to a flat file and process like other logs.  Other options might be [JDBC River](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc).

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested to know where the data is stored originally (DB, pushing straight from a server..).  However, I initially used the ELK stack to pull data back from a DB server using a batch file utilizing BCP (running on a scheduled task) and storing it to a flat file, monitoring the file with Logstash, and manipulating the data inside the LS config (grok filter).  You may also consider a simple console/web application to manipulate the data before grokking with Logstash.

If possible, I would attempt to pull your data via SQL Server SPROC/BCP command and match the returned, complete message within Logstash.  You can then store the information in a single index.

I hope this helps as I am by no means an expert, but I will be happy to answer more questions for you if you get a little more specific with the details of your current data storage; namely how the data is entering Logstash.  RabbitMQ is another valuable tool to take a look at for your input source.